# Convert 2 text line of integers into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, bufferedreader

I have some text lines like this

```
14 14 14 14

32 32 32 32
```

I want to convert into 2D array with BufferReader. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am hoping you are looking for convert string array in buffer

```
public int[][] convertTo2DArray(String filename) {
    int[][] array = null;
    
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
        String line;
        int row = 0;
        
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] elements = line.split(" ");
            
            if (array == null) {
                array = new int[elements.length][];
            }
            
            array[row] = new int[elements.length];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                array[row][i] = Integer.parseInt(elements[i]);
            }
            
            row++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return array;
}


String filename = "path/to/your/file.txt";
int[][] result = convertTo2DArray(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

By splitting your lines with the lines() method of BufferedReader, you can then use a map to split numbers with spaces. (using this regular expression allows to split even if there is more than one space character)

```java
        String input = "14 14 14 14\n32 32 32 32\n";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input));

        int[][] array = reader.lines()
                .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+"))
                        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                        .toArray())
                .toArray(int[][]::new);
```